# PWA manifest json is set to display: fullscreen - It works on Android device but doesn't work on Windows desktop

Tags: progressive-web-apps, fullscreen, manifest.json

I couldn't find any previous discussion about this particular situation.

Why won't the app start in fullscreen mode on Windows while it successfully does so on Android?

Testing was done with Chrome 95.

My `manifest.json` contains,

```
"display": "fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 2):

Fullscreen mode is currently not supported for desktop due to security concern (origin display)
See : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=850465